# How to configure/use Flash player debug version

Tags: flash, debugging

I've installed the Flash 11 (latest) activex plugin debug version from the Adobe Flash site (I'm using IE to launch the content on Windows 7).  I'm trying to see if I can determine what's causing a 3rd party flash file from working correctly.

However, I can't seem to find any documentation as to how to actually use or configure the debugger for this version.  I've looked all over the Flash site but perhaps I am blind.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply go to the site and view the content that needs to be debugged. A error console will pop up if there are any errors generated by the flash movie you are viewing. Basically the debug version just replaces your normal version in your browser(s)

Comment: So there are no configuration options and no way to manually start the debugger?

Comment: Seems like you need to set a text file called mm.cfg http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/configure-debugger-version-flash-player.html

Answer (score 0):

"So there are no configuration options and no way to manually start the debugger? "

Second question first: the "debugger" is the "Flash Player debug version" - when you installed it, you have the debugger in place.

Configure it so it should display the traces that the code spits out, in a logfile.
The comment provided by "keeg" tells where the info is (here it is again):
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/configure-debugger-version-flash-player.html

or here: (they are pretty much the same)
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ed6.html

mm.cfg contents should be a textfile like this:

```
 ErrorReportingEnable=1
 TraceOutputFileEnable=1
```

Comment: And the logs files will be in ```C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs```